# How to level two floors?

Tags: flooring, subfloor

I have two rooms with different floor level
The wall is removed so now I need the floors to be all level.

The higher floor has plywood
Should I try to put 2x4 and nail into concrete foundation and level with shims then plywood?

Or is there a proper way to do this without messing up the foundation and still not level?

[image]

Comment: Why are these two floors at different levels?  Is the subfloor also at different heights or is there just a different build-up in one vs. the other?

Comment: The concrete floor used to be garage and was permitted for living space. It's been like that for 10 years I guess. I have not looked in the subfloor yet but possibly they are not level either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, as long as you don't have a door threshold that would be a very likely trip hazard, your plan is almost right. Of course, it would be best to remove any surface reason possible in the high room. However, that floor is tongue & groove 2x4's and may be a ceiling for a room below (as seen in the sunlight areas of your picture)...so, don't screw with it.

Conversely yes, in the low room you'd build a stud frame to mimic joists and then plywood it to match the other room's elevation. Although, there's no need to nail it down nor glue it as the high room's floor edge and the walls would keep it tightly in place...your frame would be the same as a stud wall with a top and bottom plate securing the studs/joists.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this comment "that floor is tongue & groove 2x4's"? Which part are you looking at? There is no room below as that is ground level.

Comment: Yep, the ends of the T&G 2x4's can be seen under the removed wall's sole plate where the sunlight hits it. Personally, I'd keep them, as you barely need joists at all and you sure have plenty to screw or nail into.